# Cursor doesn't move but able to click

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, mouse, 16.10

When I move my mouse the cursor doesn't move. It stays in the top left corner but I am able to click.

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

This doesn't fix it for me.

I'm using lubuntu 16.10 with gnome (gnome-core, gnome-system-tools).

Comment: Are you on a 4K display or a multi-monitor setup?

Comment: @PatrickNegus No, one monitor at 1080p.

Comment: Do you have a nVidia GPU?

Comment: @PatrickNegus Yes, a GTX 1070

Comment: Ha, yes, please install the nVidia-367 driver.

Comment: @PatrickNegus I installed the driver, now I'm unable to start a gnome-session.

Comment: Do you experience a login loop? Or do you see a black screen? Also, ***do not*** install drivers from nVidia's website, install from the PPA. You may need to try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu).

Comment: @PatrickNegus I'm able to call tty2, so no I don't see a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same issue ! My cursor is blocked in the upper top left corner... I have a GTX1070 in a laptop.

00I tried to install the 637, 370 375 drivers from PPA and put nomodeset in the boot line but I can't boot...

Anyone have found a solution ?

Comment: Try press Strg + Alt + F1 or Strg + Alt + F2 or Strg + Alt + F3... until you see a login screen

Comment: I tried but don't see any login screen...

Comment: I don't know what can I try now....

Comment: Are you able to boot ubuntu?

Comment: To boot yes but I can't reach the login screen with the nvidia driver and the nomodeset
It stays blocked with a line from Nvidia... 

It's really weird because without any driver, everything work fine except the cursor which doesn't move.....

Comment: You should be able to open a login screen, try it agian and wait a little bit.

Comment: I am trying now, I'll keep you up to date.
I installed the 375.20 drivers from PPA and do I have to put the nomodeset arg ?

Comment: I tried withouth the nomodeset and I am blocked with the clean /.......

Comment: I'll try with the nomodeset

Comment: Not working... Still blocked on the clean line...